# Routing custom, delete action with has many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a has many through association.

Firms have many Users through Follows. I want Users to be able to Follow Firms. - I am using Devise for the users.

I have custom actions for both following a firm and unfollowing a firm.  The follow action is working but i am having trouble with the unfollow.

```
 def follow
  @firm = Firm.find(params[:id])
  @firm.users << current_user
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @firm }
  end
 end

def unfollow
 @firm = Firm.find(params[:id])
 current_user.follows.find_by_firm_id(@firm.id).destroy
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to firms_url }
end
```

end
in my routes.rb

```
resources :firms do
  member do
   post 'follow'
   delete 'unfollow'
  end
end
```

and in my firms view

```
 <%= link_to 'unfollow', unfollow_firm_path(firm), :method => 'delete' %>
```

I get the following error

```
NoMethodError in FirmsController#unfollow

undefined method `follows' for nil:NilClass
```

My rake routes command shows the following

```
  follow_firm POST   /firms/:id/follow(.:format)   firms#follow
  unfollow_firm DELETE /firms/:id/unfollow(.:format) firms#unfollow
```

If you have any ideas i would be very grateful!

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `undefined method 'follows' for nil:NilClass` comes from:

`current_user.follows.find_by_firm_id(@firm.id).destroy`

You need to test that a user is logged in so that `current_user` is not `nil`.

Perhaps?:

`current_user.follows.find_by_firm_id(@firm.id).destroy if current_user`

Comment: I see, thank you! I have given that a try and it now seems to be finding the action, however it now seems to terminate the session without deleting the follow. This leads to a request the login again.

Comment: It seemed like you had no session, otherwise current_user would not be nil

Comment: ok, well that helps, means I know where to start looking now! Thanks for the help Dan.